# Randomly inaccessible app settings in azure function local.settings.json

Tags: c#, azure-functions, appsettings

I have an azure function with an app setting in the local.settings.json file. Sometimes when I start my function to debug, I get to a line to retrieve the setting and it is null. Other times it is the string from the json. There doesn't seem to be a rhyme or reason to it. Is there a way to force it to get the correct value every time? Is it some race condition when the debugger attaches?

My Function code:

```
[FunctionName("MyAzureFunction")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    // this string is null sometimes, sometimes not
    var baseApiString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiBaseUrl"];

    //...more code
}
```

My local.settings.json file:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "ApiBaseUrl": "http://myurl.api.local/"
    }
}
```

Using Azure 2.9